# Smallest possible size of the set X + Y, where X and Y are sets of integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are two sets of integers, both of size $n$, then the set $X+Y=\{x + y\ |\ x\in X\ \text{and}\ y\in Y\}$ has size greater than or equal to $2n-1$.

I'm having some difficulty proving this. I figured a good approach might be to give a proof by induction. The base step is fine, but I'm having trouble completing the inductive step. Any hints or tips would be appreciated.

What I have so far is as follows:

**Base step:** Let $n=1$ and suppose that $|X|=|Y|=1$. Then $X\ \text{and}\ Y$ both have one element, say $a\in X\ \text{and}\ b\in Y$.Then $X+Y = \{a+b\}$ which has size $1 = 2(1)-1$. Hence, the claim is true for $n=1$.

**Inductive hypothesis:** Suppose that there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|X|=|Y|=k$ and $|X+Y|\geq 2k-1$.

**Inductive step:** Let $n=k+1$ and suppose that $|X|=|Y|=n$. Let $a\in X\ \text{and}\ b\in Y$. Then $X\setminus\{a\}\ \text{and}\ Y\setminus\{b\}$ both have size $k$.

And that is all I have. My thinking being that I need a way of getting from sets with size $k+1$ to sets with size $k$  in order to apply the inductive hypothesis, perhaps making use of $X+Y=X\setminus\{a\}\cup\{a\}+Y\setminus\{b\}\cup\{b\}$ with $|X\setminus\{a\}+X\setminus\{b\}| \geq 2k-1$ by the inductive hypothesis. Am I headed in the right direction? Any hints would be much appreciated. Alternative methods are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $a$ be the smallest element of $X$ and $b$ be the largest element of $Y$. How many elements are in $X+Y$ that aren't in $(X\setminus a) + (Y\setminus b)$?